# how to auto generate permalink in codeigniter like wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, url, permalinks

I'm working on CodeIgniter application in this system I have the option to create dynamic pages `title` and `content` from admin panel both are stored in the database. But I want to auto-generate `permalink` URL in CodeIgniter like WordPress after `page` published?

**For Example**

```
the page title name test 
the function should be created 
http://localhost/codeigniter/test after form data stored in the database
```

**Page Controller**

```
class Pages extends CIF_Controller {

public $layout = 'full';
public $module = 'pages';
public $model = 'Pages_model';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model($this->model);
    $this->_primary_key = $this->{$this->model}->_primary_keys[0];
    $this->permission();
}


public function index() {

     $this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'pages.*, menu.title as menu';
     $this->{$this->model}->joins = array(
        'menu' => array('menu.menu_id = pages.menu_id', 'inner')

    );

    $data['items'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
    $this->load->view($this->module . '/index', $data);

}

public function manage($id = FALSE) {
    $data = array();

     $this->{$this->model}->custom_select = 'pages.*, menu.title as menu';
     $this->{$this->model}->joins = array(
        'menu' => array('menu.menu_id = pages.menu_id', 'inner')

    );

    if ($id) {
        $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
        $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
        if (!$data['item'])
            show_404();
    } else {
        $data['item'] = new Std();

    }
    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_id', 'select menu', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'content', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('link', 'link', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        $this->load->view($this->module . '/manage', $data);

    else {
        $this->{$this->model}->title = $this->input->post('title');
        $this->{$this->model}->menu_id = $this->input->post('menu_id');
        $this->{$this->model}->content = $this->input->post('content');
        $this->{$this->model}->menulink = $this->input->post('link');
        $this->{$this->model}->save();
        redirect('admin/' . $this->module);
    }
}

public function delete($id = false) {
    if (!$id)
        show_404();
    $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
    $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
    if (!$data['item'])
        show_404();
    $this->{$this->model}->delete();
    redirect('admin/' . $this->module);
}
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I use a method in my model ('Pages_model' in your case) that stores the page to generate the url, that takes the title as input and returns an unique URL, which I then add to the database field 'url'.

The URL need to be cleaned from spaces and unwanted characters. As my language is Swedish we also want to rewrite some characters, å to a etcetera. Then we need to check that the url is not duplicate, if it is the case I just add an `uniqid()` to the url, you can think of other approaches. Here is an example of how the method can be written:

```
function make_url($title)
{
    // rewrite special characters
    $url = str_replace('é','e',$title);
    $url = str_replace('å','a',$url);
    $url = str_replace('ä','a',$url);
    $url = str_replace('ö','o',$url);
    $url = str_replace('Å','A',$url);
    $url = str_replace('Ä','A',$url);
    $url = str_replace('Ö','O',$url);
    // rewrite spaces and multiple dashes to single dashes
    $url = str_replace(' ','-',$url);
    $url = str_replace('--','-',$url);
    $url = str_replace('---','-',$url);
    $url = str_replace('----','-',$url);
    // remove all other characters
    $url = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/','',$url);
    // make url lowercase
    $url = strtolower($url);

    // check if url already used (in 'pages' table)
    $q = $this->db->where('url',$url)->get('pages');
    if ($q->num_rows()): 
        $url = $url . '-' . uniqid();
    endif;
    return $url;
}
```

So adding this model method and then modifying the `Pages_model->save()` method to add the url field to the database with `$this->make_url($title)` with your posted title.